# Botman not listen answer and turn again in payload

Tags: php, chatbot, facebook-messenger-bot, botman

#### Description:

I'm starting to do well on Botman studio. But now, for the last 20 minutes, I've had a strange reaction.

I listen paylod 'GET_STARTED' on Messenger.
When the discussion arrives on the menu. I use quick_replies.
The bot doesn't wait for the answer and acts as if I rewrote 'GET_STARTED' to him while no. After four loops, menu is finally waiting for my answer and the thread resumes normally.

#### Logs:

```
[2019-09-01 12:43:47] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341826388,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341826060,"postback":{"title":"Get Started","payload":"GET_STARTED"}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:00] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341831126,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341831113,"delivery":{"mids":["VMkkGlokptGTagVkndbr6EV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4TSTDDnkwkmaqYAYDlPpEH_OvRgyWk-xgvD1wSdE4nd5w"],"watermark":1567341830922}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:00] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341832634,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341832620,"delivery":{"mids":["fLyEFrHqH9bMZETlFqgh6UV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4T_VrgfYJV58Abtev9aSDGrO8lx1qKAVlB2urJIAK3pKw"],"watermark":1567341832419}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:00] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341834180,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341834166,"delivery":{"mids":["ocy78S9E_bA1EmLPDO6ZkUV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4QKv1RIgQug6EUhi3L1LoPRj5xLtivjpvsn7V0SMkjMrQ"],"watermark":1567341833927}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:00] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341835709,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341835695,"delivery":{"mids":["sjGFU62XxIfYnuRAAi1OOUV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4QP-BdpA4mTxwDU1_dy9hF4_ijGc3SDckZwlii5tZvuJA"],"watermark":1567341835489}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:00] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341836441,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341826060,"postback":{"title":"Get Started","payload":"GET_STARTED"}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:12] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341839329,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341839314,"delivery":{"mids":["8E4Gf_ela9_uIwjOrO2xY0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4SZZbKUbKCETggL_QEJVqIP908D2SRkAqjzlWQmooJotg"],"watermark":1567341839084}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:12] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341844043,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341844029,"delivery":{"mids":["_6gzh7f8b_Zw5ot8Timys0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4SL-uJsdcnILXivrllTQPiS8NH281V6_88SYIRCOQELRw"],"watermark":1567341843807}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:13] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341845491,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341845477,"delivery":{"mids":["xa7T7x9OTUE3hKIg5WI0gkV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4Rolwv3rw8nwSStZki3sXZaR10ILvoB2TQeWlA7pQO6UQ"],"watermark":1567341845268}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:13] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341846560,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341826060,"postback":{"title":"Get Started","payload":"GET_STARTED"}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:25] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341847017,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341846999,"delivery":{"mids":["SLrB313bTmCxF0sGcKJ1fUV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4Rpp-2xrQpykMgk2EOIgoRgKM5kn2EZmw8c8YGrjjRP6w"],"watermark":1567341846809}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:25] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341848500,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341848483,"delivery":{"mids":["mVry_RCwvaDsc7PuGCKGTkV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4StDaq7aH-sN-ZDxw62zRerdvkc8EqnI8c7OZ5kzSTLzg"],"watermark":1567341848274}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:25] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341852067,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341852053,"delivery":{"mids":["bCLqiPe4RlyFQjW-g_gjmkV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4TJI9hzsHv8Wyygq6uhBJQt49IEKUo7UM90lcJy1JAUlA"],"watermark":1567341851845}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:25] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341856720,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341856707,"delivery":{"mids":["obcY3wZiH_-XUZO449CzN0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4S8QOT13l0IoiKFw7i3nOksriDD_OASG_4MONo9UgsZPQ"],"watermark":1567341856394}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:25] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341856791,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341826060,"postback":{"title":"Get Started","payload":"GET_STARTED"}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:38] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341858122,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341858109,"delivery":{"mids":["SEVTKJpVnArDE7whFvWKFEV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4Rl1boedCGsAiIFPmVq07k_VWLZLv7EgrS39U0SVZFrLQ"],"watermark":1567341857851}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:38] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341859606,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341859593,"delivery":{"mids":["UP-EO4euQXoDYYTm-wU7K0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4QG7OMXjiki1kHuDODZqjlfPRTuTc_aFKqNEiWss9GT6Q"],"watermark":1567341859408}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:38] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341861223,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341861210,"delivery":{"mids":["gBFmPoFpnWLfINLdoYMaj0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4SpmPDN8V-oD1lDSQDikRGLxK-Ds1EllZy_sGECKKp6qA"],"watermark":1567341860999}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:38] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341864766,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341864749,"delivery":{"mids":["s1gwq9ZYk8zAlT8q9VVWx0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4Ttt7sLbzkJ0o1Ws9nPeN05om8gi53XOqkMoIwJdhimZQ"],"watermark":1567341864559}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:38] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341869406,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341869392,"delivery":{"mids":["H2hY2Leddhm5NSjoLafid0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4TdCEoUx8fKfV1k71dV84fEGdiXqv2G58DIaWMoZt83UQ"],"watermark":1567341869199}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:38] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341870919,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341870904,"delivery":{"mids":["X02cmDV56l5IdgxQgh2Dc0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4Sr2oKKLrGlT7We3JcWQ5DAeLYu-itjUXaCp62dYRXCyg"],"watermark":1567341870679}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:38] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341872340,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341872327,"delivery":{"mids":["9yr7flT92NcbC4io7unTY0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4TrcJGUNiQGj2Jhy3xAy8eD7SLP2LBr-hgDmsY_b_WTLA"],"watermark":1567341872110}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:39] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341873789,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341873777,"delivery":{"mids":["admv9287Ob3KdDT0FlL8j0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4TMTTGVhJrMDgY0Qo-tvVxpXl-iCyxlyP3Obme7VbOUPg"],"watermark":1567341873548}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:39] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341856791,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341826060,"postback":{"title":"Get Started","payload":"GET_STARTED"}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:51] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341877923,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341877907,"delivery":{"mids":["wJsghfNdLPH--x__UYBVVUV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4RoKSzjA2RyLucewxgHcHEXZaSsCWX_xidvRQeXH_IMEw"],"watermark":1567341877234}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:51] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341882585,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341882570,"delivery":{"mids":["ls6AxUga8YykDAh4GJHyKkV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4RhoPUTACFsJP-GrQz4haoTy3VlOtrJyoplsEnE6OzpyQ"],"watermark":1567341882367}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:51] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341884082,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341884068,"delivery":{"mids":["LKaZN8aehPUTOPTg6aX0U0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4SvlbD1yR6DKjeoLNQjOLpSz1TAqu4BEpe0aX8LPqnNUQ"],"watermark":1567341883851}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:51] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341885527,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341885513,"delivery":{"mids":["FPP-0Ju4NymZnnuEg3Wgn0V7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4SycqrKoPogv-XJUXez-FGWw4QaPy0dJicKbPkc_8unzg"],"watermark":1567341885296}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:51] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341886976,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341886960,"delivery":{"mids":["5zwsfyFc1Zdie99gWLHP1kV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4QdsRBVJokxSxbuQbF_tW7XmRu0ESEOTm1RPcgETmQdqQ"],"watermark":1567341886756}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:44:52] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341890972,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341890958,"delivery":{"mids":["dZC8FqylQOIBNxjI6uoWpEV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4QCzn9EUb-Ha-IjiW15oPnE8YBgsrBuuvQOdnoARi_DBA"],"watermark":1567341890510}}]}]} 
[2019-09-01 12:46:34] local.INFO: incoming {"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"2501649336532279","time":1567341992751,"messaging":[{"sender":{"id":"2386144641407790"},"recipient":{"id":"2501649336532279"},"timestamp":1567341992439,"message":{"mid":"3RQ53RHBLH3fKbFAR2tkmUV7bchRDU8EvcdGd4ZML4THZGzeMiKsK6Vk6fiWpPywXZiG-SvMJfc5q4HAl2tKYQ","text":" Déposer","nlp":{"entities":{"location":[{"suggested":true,"confidence":0.87161,"value":"époser","type":"value"}],"sentiment":[{"confidence":0.73850178557994,"value":"positive"}]},"detected_locales":[{"locale":"fr_XX","confidence":0.9999}]},"quick_reply":{"payload":"FIND_SOMEONE"}}}]}]}
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

**app/routes/botman.php**

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;

use App\Http\Middleware\AddTypingIndicator;
use App\Conversations\ExampleConversation;
use App\Conversations\OnBoardingConversation;
use BotMan\BotMan\BotMan;
use BotMan\BotMan\Middleware\Dialogflow;

$botman = resolve('botman');

$middleware = new AddTypingIndicator();
$botman->middleware->sending($middleware);

$botman->hears('start|GET_STARTED', function ($bot){
    $bot->startConversation(new OnboardingConversation());
})->stopsConversation();
```

**app/Controllers/OnboardingConversation**

```php
namespace App\Conversations;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Conversations\Conversation;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Incoming\Answer;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Actions\Button;
use BotMan\BotMan\Messages\Outgoing\Question;
use App\Conversations\InitProfileConversation;
use App\Subscriber;

class OnBoardingConversation extends Conversation
{

    /**
     * Start the conversation.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->welcomeUser();
    }

    private function welcomeUser(){
        $this->bot->typesAndWaits(2);
        $this->say(' Salut '. $this->bot->getUser()->getFirstName() .' ! ');
        $this->say('...');
        $this->say('...');
        return $this->askAboutUserModule();
    }

    private function askAboutUserModule(){
        $this->bot->typesAndWaits(2);
        $question = Question::create('Que souhaites-tu faire ?')
            ->addButtons([
                Button::create('OPTION_1')->value('OPTION_1'),
                Button::create('OPTION_2')->value('OPTION_2'),
                Button::create('OPTION_3')->value('OPTION_1'),
                Button::create('OPTION_4)->value('OPTION_4'),
            ]);

        return $this->ask($question, function (Answer $answer) {
            switch ($answer->getValue()){
                case 'OPTION_1' :
                    return $this->bot->startConversation(new InitProfileConversation());
                default :
                    $this->bot->typesAndWaits(2);
                    return $this->say('Youps');
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for help,
Valentin

Comment: FIX : DO NOT USE  'return' in switch